# Given that equation is a positive constant, equal roots, find value of k

Tags: roots, constants

I am having trouble solving this equation. It reads...

> Given that the equation $kx^2+12x+k = 0$, where $k$ is a positive constant, has equal roots, find the value of $k$.

I am not sure where to start as there is two unknown variables, $k$ and $x$ so I don't think I can factorise. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Solve in $x.$ Then, made the roots equal and you will get the value of $k.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** as $k>0$ is *fixed*, this equation is a second degree equation in the variable $x$.
There is one root iff the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) is 0.
In you case:
$$
12^2- 4\times k\times k = 0
$$

Comment: How did you get the `-4` in `12^2 - 4 x k x k = 0`?

Comment: The discriminant of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is $b^2 - 4ac$. Here $b = 12$ and $a = c = k > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$p(x)=kx^2+12x+k=\text { (double root) }k(x-a)^2=kx^2-2kax+ka^2$

Equate coefficients so that $a^2=1$ and $2ka=-12$

Note that the general form of a quadratic with a double root is $a(x-b)^2=0$ with a double root at $x=b$.